# Adding column names to unnamed columns

Tags: python, pandas

I feel like this should be easy, but I can't seem to get it.  I have a dataframe like this:

```
 AGGREP   2
 POPARA   3
 CAREX    7
```

I want to name the columns and am trying this code:

```
df.columns=['Species', 'Count']
```

but it doesn't work. The dataframe prints but without the names. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Can you post `df.info()` are you sure you have 2 columns as your code should've worked unless you realy only have 1 column because the first column is in fact your index

Comment: It looks like its actually a Series and not a dataframe, I think I need to convert it

Comment: To convert it you can just do `df = pd.DataFrame(data = s).reset_index() df.columns = ['Species', 'Count']`